# Node JS: Accessing inherited function in subclass's function

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, compoundjs

Let's say I have two classes, `Base` and `Child`.  Base is the base class that Child will be inheriting from.  Here's the code to visualize this:

**Base.js**

```
function Base(init) {

}

function log() {
  console.log('here');
}
Base.prototype.log = log;

module.exports = Base;
```

**Child.js**

```
var Base = require('../Base.js');

var Child = module.exports = function Child(init) {
  Base.call(this, init);
};

require('util').inherits(Child, Base);

function test() {
  this.log();  // doesn't work
  Base.prototype.log();  // Works but is quite ugly
  Child.super_.prototype.log();  // Works but is even uglier
}

Child.prototype.test = test;
```

What I would absolutely love to do is something like `this.log()` or even `log()` would be nice.  I realize I can set a variable to that in my inherited class, but then I would have to do that for every class that inherits `Base`, which is definitely not ideal.  So my question is, can I do something like `this.log()` without having to set a variable in the inherited class?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Don't both of those fail, because `this` has the wrong value during the call to `log`?

Comment: Yes, `this.log()` just fails and crashes the server, but I put it in to show what I was trying and wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an FYI, I ended up putting this in the `global` variable that Node creates for you.  I realize that's bad practice, but it's a logging mechanism that needs to be used by any class, controller, etc., so I don't think it's that terrible of a solution.

However, in Compound, you can create **no_eval** controllers, which means they look like typical prototypical functions... so you can essentially create a **mixin**, or I can require my mixin and use it like a class... like this:

```
var ControllerMixin = require(process.cwd() + 'app/mixins/ControllerMixin.js');
var Log;

var LoggerController = module.exports = function LoggerController(init) {
  ControllerMixin.call(this, init);  // mixin approach
  Log = require(process.cwd() + 'app/utils/LoggerMixin.js')(init);  // class approach
};

LoggerController.prototype.index = function index(controller) {
  controller.logMessage('blah');  // using mixin
  Log.logError('hi');  // using class
  global.logWarning('yep');  // global approach
  return controller.send({success: true});
};
```

So there are options... just have to find what you think is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**:

From your comment below, replying to my statment that `this.log()` should work:

> Well, so that's the thing. When I'm in Child's test function, `this` is an empty object, so I'm assuming somewhere down the line I'm not getting the proper scope.

You haven't shown how you're calling `test`, but I suspect that's where the problem is. Provided you call it via a `Child` instance:

```
var c = new Child();
c.test();
```

...then within the call, `this` will be the child instance, which will inherit (indirectly) the `Parent.prototype` object with its `log` property.

But how you call it is important. This wouldn't work, for instance:

```
var c = new Child();
var f = c.test;
f();
```

If you do that, within the call to the function, `this` will be the global object (or `undefined` if you're in strict mode), not a `Child` instance. This is because in JavaScript, `this` is set primarily by how a function is called, and calling it like that doesn't set `this` to what you want.

This matters for callbacks, because passing in `c.test` as a callback:

```
someFunctionThatUsesACallback(c.test);
```

...means the code calling back won't set `this` for you.

If you need to do that, `Function#bind` will help:

```
var f = c.test.bind(c); // Returns a version of c.test that, when called,
                        // will have `this` set to `c`
f();                    // Works, `this` is the `Child` instance
```

And similarly:

```
someFunctionThatUsesACallback(c.test.bind(c));
```

More (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

**Original Answer**:

If you set up the prototype hierarchy correctly, and `Child.prototype` doesn't have `log` on it (and you don't put a `log` property on instances), then you should be able to use `this.log();` just fine. If you can't, then the hierarchy hasn't been set up correctly.

I don't know what `util.inherits` does, but setting up the relationship between `Child` and `Parent` correctly isn't complicated:

```
function Parent() {
}
Parent.prototype.log = function() {
    console.log("log called");
};

function Child () {
    Parent.call(this);
}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child; // This line is largely optional, but a good idea

// Usage
var c = new Child();
c.log(); // "log called"
```

But if you override `log` in your `Child.prototype` or assign a `log` property to instances, and you want to use `Parent`'s version of `log`, then of course you can't just use `this.log()` because the property doesn't refer to `Parent.prototype.log` anymore.

When you need to call the parent version of something (I call them "supercalls," and I don't think that's original), you have to do more work:

I usually set up hierarchies like this by passing the parent constructor into a function I use to build the child, e.g.:

```
var Child = (function(Super) {
    var pp = Super.prototype;

    function Child() {
    }
    Child.prototype = Object.create(pp);

    Child.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        // Call `log` with appropriate `this`
        pp.log.call(this);
    };

    return Child;
})(Parent);
```

By always using that pattern, I avoid having to write `Parent` inside the `Child` code (I use the `Super` arg instead), so if I need to rebase `Child`, I just change what I pass into the function.

Because that's fairly ugly (for instance, it's unclear at the top of `Child` that it derives from `Parent`, since `Parent` is at the bottom) and involves boilerplate code I don't feel the need to write again every time, I wrote a simple helper script for it I call [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/), which makes it look like this:

```
var Child = Lineage.define(Parent, function(p, pp) {
    p.doSomething = function() {
        // Call `log` with appropriate `this`
        pp.log.call(this);
    };
});
```

Note that `Lineage` passes in both the `Child` and `Parent` prototypes as arguments, making it concise to use them (and since you get to pick those argumetn names, you can use whatever terminology works for you — I use `p` for the prototype of the "class" being created [`Child` in the above], and `pp` for the parent's prototype, etc.).

Comment: So what this is telling me is that my actual question is not possible... that in every class's function, I have to access the log function in some strange fashion.  Therefore, I think my initial way with assigning a var as log is the easiest route.  Don't get me wrong, this is an excellent answer, but it's not what I'm really looking for.

Comment: @incutonez: Again, unless you're overriding `log`, then with a correct hierarchy (which is easy to do) `this.log()` should work. You only have to do other things if you're overriding `log` at the `Child` level and you want to use the `Parent` version. If that's what you need to do, and you assign `log` to a variable, then to call it with the correct `this` value, you have to do this `yourVariable.call(this);` So that's basically the same as `pp.log.call(this);` FWIW, ES6 will make that *lots* easier, but even if you run Node with the harmony flag, it doesn't have it yet.

Comment: Well, so that's the thing... I am trying to do the former (not overriding log in Child).  When I'm in Child's test function, `this` is an empty object, so I'm assuming somewhere down the line I'm not getting the proper scope.  Unfortunately, most of that is hidden from me, as I'm using CompoundJS as my MVC framework.  I'm also assuming that with how inheritance is set up in ES5, it just doesn't work like I'm expecting.  And regarding Harmony, yeah, I'm patiently waiting for that to come out... I've heard that classes will be much easier.

Comment: @incutonez: Ah, I think I know what's going on. The problem isn't that the hierarchy isn't set up right, it's the way you're calling `test`. I've updated the answer with the details.

Comment: Yep, and I believe this is where I'm going to have to say, "I don't know."  The function `test` is actually a route, and Compound takes care of calling that for me... so I would imagine your assumption about why it wouldn't work is right.  Sorry for any confusion... I tried to leave Compound out of this and make it a generic question, but it looks like I'm getting tripped up with how Compound is handling it.

Comment: @incutonez: Wherever it is that you're handling the function to Compound, try the `bind` thing, that may clear up the problem.

Comment: I'll have to dig down into the Compound code because the framework is the one that actually takes care of creating the class and calling its functions... I only set up how the class should look, but I believe you're right on with the `bind` option.

Answer (score 0):

The standard [`inherits`](https://github.com/isaacs/inherits) function from node.js is (in my humble opinion) very bad code. Instead I prefer to use [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment) to create classes:

```
// base.js

var augment = require("augment");

var Base = module.exports = augment(Object, function () {
    this.constructor = function (init) {

    };

    this.log = function () {
        console.log("here");
    };
});

// child.js

var augment = require("augment");
var Base = require("./base");

var Child = module.exports = augment(Base, function (base) {
    this.constructor = function (init) {
        base.constructor.call(this, init);
    };

    this.test = function () {
        this.log();
    };
});
```

In addition [augment.js](https://github.com/javascript/augment/blob/master/augment.js) is just 20 lines of code and can be used everywhere.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting approach, and more along the lines of what I'm looking for.  I may try to adapt this to my solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Every answer I see online either looks complicated, or relies on external libraries. Why not just boil down to the basics, assuming you use a custom type design pattern, which is very similar to traditional OOP. 
**parent.js**

```
//the main parent class
// class Parent


module.exports = Parent;

function Parent(a) {
    if (!(this instanceof Parent)) {
        return new Parent(a);
    }
    this.a = a; //Some parent variable
}

Parent.prototype = {

    // Instantiate child:
    getChild: function() {
        var Child = require('./child');
        return new Child(this);
    },

    // Some parent function, print some text:
    printText: function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }
};
```

**child.js**

```
//Similar to class Child extends Parent


module.exports = Child;

function Child(parent) {

    this.parent = parent;
}

Child.prototype = {

    // Prints Parent Variable:
    printParentVariable: function() {
        console.log(this.parent.a);
    },

    // Calls Parent Function:
    callParentFunction: function() {
        this.parent.printText('Child calling parent function.');
    }
};
```

**test.js**

```
var parent = require('./parent')('parent text'); //instantiate parent with some text

var child = parent.getChild();       //create instance of a child

//*** Child has full access to its parents variables and methods ***//

console.log(child.parent.a);         //Print the parent text "parent text"
child.printParentVariable();         //Child method which prints the parent variable "parent text", identical to line above.
child.parent.printText('Child calling parent');      //Call parent method, to print provided text
child.callParentFunction();          //Calls parent method, identical to above.
```